# What are the different definitions of torsion-free connections in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus

What are the different definitions of torsion-free connections in GR?

I am summarizng torsion-less condition in various context, if you know anything about  it please let me know.

1. One typical definition of torsion is 
   \begin{align}
   T(X,Y) = \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X - [X,Y]
   \end{align}
   with this one can say torsion 
   \begin{align}
   T_{MN}{}^K = 2 \Gamma_{[MN]}{}^K = \Gamma_{MN}{}^K - \Gamma_{NM}{}^K
   \end{align}
   and demand that $T_{MN}{}^K=0$, we have symmetrized $\Gamma$ for first two indices (In above notation).

   I can re-write this as 
   \begin{align}
   [X,Y](\partial) = [X,Y](\nabla)
   \end{align}
   where $[X,Y]$ are usual Lie bracket.
2. In Physics, focusing on general relativity, they consider torsion-less connection from the beginning. In some textbook, states via geodesic equation 
   \begin{align}
   \Gamma_{\mu\nu}{}^\lambda = \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \xi^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu}
   \end{align}
   or other textbook states in terms of orthonormal basis 
   \begin{align}
   \nabla_{e_i} e_j = \nabla_{e_j} e_i = \Gamma_{ij}{}^k e_k
   \end{align}
   Above two connections imply torsion-less in its definition. (Of course, one can distinguish $\nabla_{e_i} e_j$ and $\nabla_{e_j} e_i$. $i.e$, One can define torsion as a subtraction between them. )
3. Or some textbook as Carroll, defines torsion as a commutation relation from covariant derivatives $i.e$, 
   \begin{align}
   [\nabla_A, \nabla_B] V_K = - R_{MNK}{}^L V_L - T_{MN}{}^K \nabla_L V_K
   \end{align}
   apparently, with some computation we see that 
   \begin{align}
   T_{MN}{}^K = 2 \Gamma_{[MN]}{}^K
   \end{align}
   which agrees with first statement.
4. Or one can deduce this from 
   \begin{align}
   L_X(\partial) = L_X(\nabla)
   \end{align}
   where $L_X$ is a Lie-deriative along $X$ direction.  Applying for $V_K$ we have $\Gamma_{MN}{}^K = \Gamma_{NM}{}^K$

Comment: Would it be a good idea to include a specific question in your post? It looks like , to me anyway, you want to discuss the pros and cons of the various definitions.

Comment: If you want to turn your findings into a resource, the most common way to do it is to post a question (like, "what are the different definitions of torsion-free connections in GR?"), answer your own question (using the stuff you posted above), and accept that answer.

Comment: Otherwise, it's unclear what we should do with this question...

Comment: @knzhou, Thanks! That was my intention!. I changed my question

Comment: ...and the question here is?

Comment: Is the a physical interpretation to torsion, or is it just a math construct which is helpful in dealing with GR equations?